# Filtering an array based on a second array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, comparison

I have two data arrays:

```
$arrnames=('a','b','c')
$arrtypes=('x','y','z')
```

and I have a lookup array:

```
$arrlookup=('y','z')
```

I need to return the elements in `$arrnames` where the matching element in $arrtypes is contained in `$arrlookup`. I've been playing with `foreach` looping over `$arrnames` and looking at the same element in `$arrtypes` by index but it's getting sloppy and I know there has to be a better way.

I've seen some similar questions, but not anything that strikes me as specifically answering this problem. Being a Powershell very newbie I'm still learning how to adapt examples to my needs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code (technique used as applied to above example - actual code is using complex arrays derived from an XML file and has a lot of debugging code so copy/paste is impractical)

```
foreach ($a in $arrnames) {
    $t=$arrtypes[$arrnames.IndexOf($a)]
    if ($arrlookup.Contains($t)) {
       $arrresult+=$a
    }
)
```

$arrresult should contain the members of $arrnames that have a type (from $arrtypes) that is in $arrlookup.

Is there a way to use object methods, filtering and the pipeline to simply extract the elements without a foreach loop

Edit - here's the actual code that creates the actual arrays - $builds is an XML document:

```
$names=$builds.builds.project.name
$types=$builds.builds.project.type
```

The lookup table is known:

```
$FXCopTypes=@('batch','component','web')
```

The XML file I also have control over, but I don't see any way to simplify it more than implementing the hash table code but with the above arrays.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: It is possible that you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. Maybe if you have control over the source you can make better use of these objects. As it stands you need a loop of somesort.

Comment: Actually I have a fair amount of control over the input. Is there a better way to structure this so that I don't need a loop?

Comment: Is this `$arrnames` and  `$arrtypes` from the _same_ data set? If this was already an object extracting the data might not be necessary. Unless you show some sample data and how it is extracted I will not know for sure. To clarify ... your code does work and you are trying to optimize it?

Comment: Better yet, instead of extracting the values into two separate arrays, create a hashtable with the `x, y, z` values as keys

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That is what my solution is but changing the input would remove that need entirely.

Comment: It seems like about the same amount of code and still requires a for loop. If I dramatically restructure the input it has a lot of downstream impacts I don't want to deal with right now. @Matt gets credit for an answer that works, even though I've decided not to implement it over my current code. Thanks all.

Comment: @RichardSchaefer When you are ready I think you might have the work of another good question that could link to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change you input inorder to be able to do anything different here. What you are asking for is `$arrnames` and `$arrtypes` to really be a hashtable. That way you can access the values using keys.

As it stands I would do this to create the hashtable. The second loop shows how to return each matching value.

```
$hash = @{} 

for($index = 0; $index -lt $arrtypes.Count; $index++){
    $hash.($arrtypes[$index]) =  $arrnames[$index]      
}

$arrresult = $arrlookup | ForEach-Object{
    $hash[$_]
}
```

This would return

```
b
c
```

If you could get your input to create that hash table then it reduces the need to rebuild it. Also if you know the lookup before hand as well you can filter it then and just have the output you want.