# Would a hash table speed this up? If so how would I do it?

Tags: arrays, powershell, dictionary

I'm looking for the negative intersection of two arrays. Each array has about 20k elements. I'm using a foreach loop over one array and looking each value up in the other array. I'm only keeping elements in the first array not found in the second array:

```
$deadpaths=@()
$ix=0
ForEach ($f in $FSBuildIDs)
{
    if (-not($blArray -like $f)) {$deadpaths+=$paths[$ix]}
    $ix++
}
```

$blArray contains valid IDs. $FSBuildIDs contains the IDs corresponding to the file system paths in $paths. The intent is to only keep the elements in $paths where the corresponding ID in $FSBuildIDS is NOT in $blArray.

Is there a better way to do this? The processing here takes an extremely long time. Both $blArray and $FSBuildIDs have about 20k elements and I suspect I'm looking at On^2 comparisons.

I thought about using a Dictionary with the elements of $FSBuildIDs as the keys and $paths as the values, but I can't figure out from the docs how to initialize and load the Dictionary (assuming this approach would speed things up). Obviously negative set intersection would be best but this isn't TSQL and I'm painfully aware that even V4 of PS doesn't support set operations.

Would using a dictionary in this problem speed up the comparisons? If so how do I create it from $FSBuildIDs and $paths? Any other techniques that might give me a performance boost vs. just iterating over these large(ish) lists?

Sample data for $blArray:

```
51012
51044
51049
51055
51058
51060
51073
51074
51077
51085
```

Sample data for $FSBuildIDs:

```
51001
51003
51005
51009
51013
51017
51018
51020
51021
51024
51026
```

Sample data for $paths:

```
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2335
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2336
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2337
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2338
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2339
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2340
\\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\0000\3774\0000\3792\0005\2341
```

This is similar to the question posed previously, but different in some aspects. I'm essentially looking for guidance on constructing a dictionary from two existing arrays. I realized after posting that I really need a dictionary from $blarray as the keys and maybe $True as the value. The value is irrelevant. The important test is whether or not the current value in $FSBuildIDs is found in $blarray. That could be a dictionary lookup based on the ID as the key. That should speed up the processing, right?

I'm not clear on the comment that I'm destroying and recreating the array each time. Is that the $deadPaths array? Simply adding to it causes that? If so would I be better using a .Net ArrayList?

Comment: This is definitely one of the slowest ways as it is destroying an rebuilding the array for every pass. Hashtable or custom object might be fine. Why not just use `Compare-Object` from the start? Can you show samples of both data sets?

Comment: Another one of your questions is in the same vein here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920549/filtering-an-array-based-on-a-second-array. Some sample data and expected output would make it easier to provide a specific solution.

Comment: I was referring to what is happening behind the scenes when you run this `$deadpaths+=$paths[$ix]`. The current `$deadpaths` is dropped and a new one is made with the extra element. Very consuming process when repeated several thousand times.

Comment: How does $paths relate to the sample arrays you posted?

Comment: $paths actually contains the data I'm processing. $FSBuildIDs are "Build IDs" constructed from the last two levels of the file paths in $paths. I looked at Compare-Object and I'd have to sort $blArray and $FSBuildIDs or set a SyncWIndow of at least 10k. If I sort $FSBuildIDs then the index into that array no longer corresponds to the index into $paths. A very large SyncWindow would use a large amount of memory although since they're only INT32 values maybe that would work.

Comment: What is the alternative to the $deadpaths problem? Using an ArrayList vs. an Array?

Comment: I see two comparisons being done. First on the builds then on the paths. Let me come up with something based on your test data. There is _no_ overlap on your id arrays. I would expect some in your real data?

Comment: As for Compare-Object the sync window is already set: "The default value is [Int32]::MaxValue". Just need to test to see what it is like

Comment: @Matt - Right, I tried to get sample that showed some overlap but it's difficult. Out of the 20k entries only about 1,300 are "not found", the rest are present in both arrays.

Comment: I was able to get a comparable list of missing IDs using Compare-Object in significantly less time. The issue now is to find the corresponding items in $paths so I can process them.

Comment: Where does $paths come form? Is it just a text file or is it the output of something like Get-ChildItem? Need to know for how I am solving your second comparison issue.

Comment: $paths is the output of a Get-Item \\server1\d$\software\anthill\var\artifacts\*\*\*\*\*\* command. It's a structured file system where the 6th folder under "artifacts" contains data and I need to get the folder sizes, but only for paths where the build ID (the 5th & 6th level of the path) are not in the list of valid build IDs ($blArray)

Comment: Ah ok..... I need to update my answer then. This will be less error prone this way too!

Comment: Thought about posting this as an answer but I didn't feel that was appropriate. I made two changes that significantly (like 90% reduction) improved the performance to the point where I have no need to pursue further enhancement. I changed $blArray and $deadpaths to ArrayLists and used ArrayList.Add() instead of "+=". That sped up building those arrays considerably. I also implemented the recommendation marked below as an answer to change my comparison from -like to -contains. That also improved it significantly. While I could squeeze out a few more seconds I don't know that it's necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve a significant improvement by using the `-contains` operator instead of `-like`.

When the left-hand side of a `-like` operation is an array, PowerShell will iterate the array and perform a `-like` comparison against each and every entry.

`-contains`, on the other hand, returns as soon as a match is found.

Consider the following example:

```
$array1 = 1..2000
$array2 = 2..2001

$like = Measure-Command {
    foreach($i in $array2){
        $array1 -like $i
    }
} |Select -Expand TotalMilliseconds

$contains = Measure-Command {
    foreach($i in $array2){
        $array1 -contains $i
    }
} |Select -Expand TotalMilliseconds

Write-Host "Operation with -like     took: $($like)ms"
Write-Host "Operation with -contains took: $($contains)ms"
```

Just like in your real-world example, we have 2 integer arrays with a large overlap. Let's see how it performs on my Windows 7 laptop (PowerShell 4.0):

[image]

I think the result speaks for itself :-)

---

That being said, you could, as you seem to anticipate, achieve an even greater improvement by populating a hashtable, using the values from the first array as keys:

```
$hashtable = $array1 |ForEach-Object -Begin {$t = @{}} -Process {
    $t[$_] = $null 
    # the value doesn't matter, we're only interested in the key lookup
} -End { $t }
```

and then use the `ContainsKey()` method on the hashtable instead of `-like`:

```
foreach($i in $array2){
    if($hashtable.ContainsKey($i)) { # do stuff }
}
```

You'll need to bump up the size of the array to see the actual difference (here using 20K items in the first array):

[image]

Final test script [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/b21a6f0629a10c83eadf)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the start of what you are looking for. As discussed in comments we are going to do two comparisons. First to get the BuildID's we need to compare from from `$FSBuildIDs` and `$blArray` then we take the result of that to compare against the list of `$paths`. I am going to assume that it is just a string array of paths for now. Note there is room for error prevention and correction here. Still just testing for now.

```
$parsedIDs = Compare-Object $blArray $FSBuildIDs | Where{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

$paths = $paths | ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name BuildID -Value (($_.Parent.Name + $_.Name) -as [int32]) -PassThru
}

$paths | Where-Object{$_.BuildID -in $parsedIDs}
```

First we compare the two ID arrays and keep the unique elements of `$FSBuildIDs`.

Next we go through the `$paths`. For each one we add a property that contains `buildid`. Where the `buildid` is the last two path elements concatenated and converted to an integer.

Once we have that a simple `Where-Object` give us the paths that have an id present from the first comparison.

Comment: I was using <= in my Compare-Object to find elements in $FSBuildIDs that are not in $$blArray. Those are the ones I need to analyze.

Comment: @RichardSchaefer I read your question in that you need the elements unique to `$FSBuildIDs` which is what I have done. Note that the order of the compared objects as parameters matters in this regard. _corresponding ID in $FSBuildIDS is NOT in $blArray_

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about building a hashtable:

```
$keyEnumerator = $FSBuildIDs.GetEnumerator()
$valEnumerator = $paths.GetEnumerator()
$idPathHash = @{}

foreach ($key in $keyEnumerator ) {
  $null = $valEnumerator.movenext()
  $idPathHash[$key] = $valEnumerator.current
}
```

Running this code on my system with a 20000 element array of fake data took 138ms.

To build the list of build ids not in the $idPathHash:

```
$buildIDsNotIn =
  foreach ($buildId in $blArray) {
    if (!$idPathHash.ContainsKey($buildId )) {
      $buildId 
    } 
  }
```

This took 50ms on my system, with 20000 items in $blArray, again with fake data.

Comment: The comparison of the two ID arrays seems to be effectively handled by Compare-Object vs. ForEach. Use of a hash table to store the ID/Path combination for retrieval based on the output of Compare-Object will be useful as part of the overall solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the size of your $blArray, but with a $blArray of 20000 items, compare-object takes about 110x longer. FWIW, looking up a key in a hashtable with a well design hash is approximately a constant time operation, whereas looking up an object in an array with a linear search is a linear time operation. With a binary search, it would be a log base 2 operation.